# c# getting current index of generic list

Tags: c#, .net, list, indexing, generics

How can i get **index** of generic list from form page? For example;

aspx.cs

```
List<string> names = new List<string>();
names.Add("a");
names.Add("b");
names.Add("c");

repeaterNames.datasource = names;
repeaterNames.DataBind();
```

aspx

```
<form>
  <repeater>
   <itemtemplate>
    **<%# Eval(?)%>**
   </itemtemplate>
  </repeater>
</form>
```

Comment: Clear the question.What do you want exactly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`ItemIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeateritem.itemindex.aspx):

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <%# Container.ItemIndex %>
</ItemTemplate>
```